# SetWindowPos() sometimes does not resize child-windows

Tags: c++, winapi

First, I use `Createprocess()` to open all desired windows. (Not Listed)

After the successful opening of the processes I find with the `FindWindow ()` and `FindWindowEx()` all available windows. (Listed)

Sometimes the function `SetWindowPos()` does not work properly. A few windows were sorted out a few not. But this case does not always occur!

For improvements I always have an open ear!

```
    //Some Variables comming from other code : numberOfWindows / numberOfStartedWindows 
//Variables
        bool trigger = true;
        bool targetProcess = true;
        HWND hwnd, hwndChilds = NULL;
        int targetsFound = 0;
        int targetsFoundMath = 0;
        bool searchWindows = true;

        //Start targetProcess
        while (targetProcess) {

            //If targetsFround == numberOfWindows then exit targetProcess.
            if (targetsFound == numberOfWindows)
            {
                targetProcess = false;
            }

            //If all Windows are Started then start search loop
            if (numberOfStartedWindows == numberOfWindows)
            {
                trigger = false;
            }

            //We starting search loop...
            if (!trigger && targetProcess) {

                //Find the Main Window.
                hwnd = FindWindow(0, _T("World of Warcraft"));
                if (hwnd)
                {
                    targetsFound += 1;

                    //Set Window Foreground and call SetWindowPos to change Position
                    if (SetForegroundWindow(hwnd)) {
                        if (!SetWindowPos(hwnd, HWND_TOP, 0, 0, 1920, 800, SWP_SHOWWINDOW))
                        {
                            cout << "Error: HWND Failed with SETWINDOWPOS" << endl;
                        }
                    }
                    //Store HWND in StoreWindows
                    StoreWindows.emplace_back(hwnd);

                    //Now we search for child Windows
                    while (searchWindows)
                    {

                        //do it if targetsFound not numberOfWindows
                        if (targetsFound != numberOfWindows)
                        {
                            //Get Child Window
                            hwndChilds = FindWindowEx(NULL, hwnd, NULL, _T("World of Warcraft"));
                            if (hwndChilds != NULL)
                            {

                                //Little Math for Position
                                targetsFoundMath = (targetsFound - 1) * 384;

                                //if window in foreground SetWindowPos.
                                if(SetForegroundWindow(hwndChilds)){
                                    if (!SetWindowPos(hwndChilds, HWND_TOP, targetsFoundMath, 800, 384, 280, SWP_SHOWWINDOW))
                                    {
                                        cout << "Error: HWNDChilds Failed with SETWINDOWPOS" << endl;
                                    }
                                }

                                /*targetsFound += 1;
                                StoreWindows.emplace_back(hwndChilds);*/

                                //If all targetsFound then quit this loop after finish
                                if (targetsFound == numberOfWindows) {
                                    searchWindows = false;
                                    cout << "false" << targetsFound << endl;
                                }

                                //StoreChild Window and Add targetsfround +1
                                targetsFound += 1;
                                StoreWindows.emplace_back(hwndChilds);
                            }
                            else {
                                searchWindows = false;
                                cout << "no more child objects found!" << endl;
                            }
                        }
                        else 
                        {
                            searchWindows = false;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        cout << "Window Size: " << StoreWindows.size() << endl;
```

Funny when I debugs:

```
RECT debugRect; 
for (int x = 0; x < StoreWindows.size(); x++)
{
    GetClientRect(StoreWindows[x], &debugRect);

    cout << debugRect.left << " " << debugRect.right<< " " << debugRect.bottom<< " " << debugRect.top << endl;
    //debugRect.right = breite vom fenster // debugRect.bottom = Höhe
}
```

The output from the Position looks good but the Window isnt on the right place :/
Debug:
[image: Debug]

Im out of ideas and hope you can help me! If you need more explanations, do not hesitate to ask.

With problems it looks so..

[image: Fold proccess]

If everything goes without problems it looks like this:

[image: Success process]

Comment: Are you overriding the position in the child window's `WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING` handler?

Comment: im not sure^^ (i think no)

Comment: how you mean that exatly? SetWindowPos() do new position. Or i forget something? Sry im new in c++

Comment: If you have an answer, write an answer. Don't out answers in the question.

Comment: Ok, thank you for the info, have added Answer :) I've seen I have a downvote and wanted to ask if the listing is unclear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the duplicate (same) window partial to be found. Because the start process takes longer than the Find Func. Now i have Fixxed the loop. (Its wait now for all success windows.)

```
bool mainWindow = false;
    bool searchHwndStrike = false;
    int targetResult = 0;
    while (true)
    {
        //Search first Window
        if (!mainWindow) {
            hwnd = FindWindow(0, _T("World of Warcraft"));
            if (hwnd != NULL)
            {

                if (SetForegroundWindow(hwnd)) {
                    if (!SetWindowPos(hwnd, HWND_TOP, 0, 0, 1920, 800, SWP_SHOWWINDOW))
                    {
                        cout << "Error: HWND Failed with SETWINDOWPOS" << endl;
                    }
                }

                cout << "Main window found." << endl;
                mainWindow = true;
                StoreWindows.emplace_back(hwnd);
            }
        }else {

            if (StoreWindows.size() < numberOfWindows) {
                hwnd = FindWindowEx(NULL, hwnd, NULL, _T("World of Warcraft"));
                if (hwnd != NULL)
                {
                    for (int x = 0; x < StoreWindows.size(); x++)
                    {
                        if (StoreWindows[x] == hwnd)
                        {
                            searchHwndStrike = true;
                        }
                    }
                    if (!searchHwndStrike)
                    {
                        cout << "Child window found." << endl;
                        cout << targetResult << endl;
                        targetResult = (StoreWindows.size()-1) * 384;

                        //if window in foreground SetWindowPos.
                        if (SetForegroundWindow(hwnd)) {
                            if (!SetWindowPos(hwnd, HWND_TOP, targetResult, 800, 384, 280, SWP_SHOWWINDOW))
                            {
                                cout << "Error: HWNDChilds Failed with SETWINDOWPOS" << endl;
                            }
                        }
                        StoreWindows.emplace_back(hwnd);

                    }
                    searchHwndStrike = false;
                }
            }
            else {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    cout << StoreWindows.size() << endl;
```